# Remove Item from array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have one javascript array i will store this array in local Storage

```
 var result;     
 result = [1,2,3,4,5];
 localStorage.setItem('result', JSON.stringify(result));
```

Above is the array result and i will set the array values to local Storage

```
function removeItem(Id){
    result= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('result'));// get array values from local Strorage
    var index = result.indexOf(Id);// find index position
    result.splice(index , 1); //and removing the Id from array
    localStorage.setItem('result', JSON.stringify(result));// result set to local storage
}
```

function call

```
var id = 1;
removeItem(id);
```

The first positioned array value is not removing from Array items. All other values will perfectly remove using this function But the first value in array not removing from array. Can anyone please suggest the better option?

Comment: function removeItem= function(Id) is wrong try var removeItem= function(Id) instead

Comment: Tried your code in console, working fine for me

Comment: With the exception of the function signature, the code is working. [Demo](http://jsbin.com/vaxeni/1/watch?js,console)

Answer (score 1):

To remove the first element you must use index value = 0 and not 1

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not an issue since the OP is using `result.indexOf(Id)` to find the index of some Id, in this case `var id = 1;`

Comment: Yup just observed that

Answer (score 0):

Try to used this function.

```
function removeItem(arr) {
    var what, a = arguments, len = a.length, ax;
    while (len  > 1 && arr.length) {
        what = a[--len ];
        while ((ax= arr.indexOf(what)) !== -1) {
            arr.splice(ax, 1);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

For example :

```
removeItem(result,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to remove items from an array is the following :

```
// as a function
function removeitem(item, arr){
    var i; while( ( i = arr.indexOf(item)) != -1)arr.splice(i, 1);
}
```

use like this

```
var result;     
result = [1,2,3,4,5];
removeitem(1, result);
```